# Why didn't File#delete throw exception when the file was not deleted?

Tags: java, exception, file-io

The following code throws assertion but not an exception.

```
if( descFile.exists() ) {
    check = descFile.delete();
    assert(check);
}
```

How can it be? Why doesn't it throw an exception if the file was not deleted?

Comment: There are several possible reasons: you don't have enough permissions, the file was already deleted by other process, the file is being used (locked) by other process...

Comment: If the file is locked, then why doesn't exception occur?

Comment: Because [`File#delete`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) will only throw an exception *If a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkDelete(java.lang.String) method denies delete access to the file*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29), `File.delete()` only throws:

> SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its
>   SecurityManager.checkDelete(java.lang.String) method denies delete
>   access to the file

So if you don't have a security manager active, you won't get an exception, just the regular return behavior, which is:

> true if and only if the file or directory is successfully deleted;
>   false otherwise